# Laravel : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::notifyNow()

Tags: php, laravel, backend

trying to learn laravel 9 from a course online , have faced this error and tried a lot to fix but No benefit :
error : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::notifyNow()
I am trying to send a notification  when some user post a post (for all users except the one who posted it).

here is the classes in my project and every thing I have tried to do:
This is the store method in the PostController :

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $post = Post::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'body' => $request->body
        ]);
        
        $users = User::where('id' , '!=' , auth()->user()->id);
        $postCreatedByUser = auth()->user()->name;
        $users->notifyNow(new PostPublished($post->id , $postCreatedByUser));
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');

    }
```

The PostPublished notification class :

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
class PostPublished extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    private $postId;
    private $postCreatedBy;

    public function __construct($postId , $postCreatedBy)
    {
        $this->postId = $postId;
        $this->postCreatedBy = $postCreatedBy;
    }

    public function via(object $notifiable): array
    {
        return ['database'];
    }

    public function toDatabase (object $notifiable): array
    {
        return [
            'postId' => $this->postId,
            'postedCreatedBy' => $this->postCreatedBy,
        ];
    }
}
```

have added the notifiable trait in the user class :

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory;
    use Notifiable;
```

aslo added :

```
Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
```

in the app.php

.... also when using

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;
Notification::send($users , new PostPublished($post->id , $postCreatedByUser));
```

I got this error :
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::routeNotificationFor()

appreciate any help , thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that the probleme is because you're calling the notifyNow on the instance of the builder not the user model you should add ->get() to the query

```
$post = Post::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'body' => $request->body
    ]);
    
    $users = User::where('id' , '!=' , auth()->user()->id)->get();
    $postCreatedByUser = auth()->user()->name;
    $users->notifyNow(new PostPublished($post->id , $postCreatedByUser));
    return redirect()->route('dashboard');
```

Comment: Yes i agree, the problem to is caused by the missing get()